# How to limit the maximum number of simultaneous connections in Nuget?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

Recently I've updated my development environment from Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013 to Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015.

I've noticed one specific change related to Nuget that completely disrupt my workflow. 
Currently, if I ask Nuget (using the GUI) to install a given package, it starts to download all of its dependencies simultaneously. 
My network is pretty bad and as consequence, the network collapses and Nuget start complaining about Timeout exceptions and, as consequence, none dependency is downloaded.

I wonder if it is possible to ask Nuget to download one dependency at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I am aware if you are using NuGet v2. Unless you work out the dependency order and download them in the correct order one at a time yourself.  The only place this concurrent operations is disabled for NuGet v3 is when running NuGet.exe from the command line on Mono.

The number of concurrent operations is 16 which is a constant in the NuGet source code. This seems to be used to restrict the number of tasks that are started. However each task may run a separate task to request something from each enabled package source.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download one dependency at a time, you can use the option 
-IgnoreDependencies to download the package and all of its dependencies one by one. See the [NuGet Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/powershell-reference#install-package) for detail. Please pay attention to the restriction of the dependency version, you can get the restriction from Dependencies on the NuGet Package Manager UI.